# Angular assets building in /dist folder

Tags: angular

I am using the flag-icon-css package that supplies you a css "font" file and all SVGs of flags.  There was an issue with the package (4x3 flags not showing properly), so I pulled all of the files out of `node_modules` and fixed the issue.

I now have all of the css and flag icons under the `src/assets/fonts` folder.  I updated my `angular.json` to reflect the changes and made sure the `flag-icon-css` folder in `node_modules` was deleted, but the flag icons are still saving in both the `/dist` and **also** `assets/fonts` folder.

Here is what my `angular.json` was changed to:

```
  "styles": [
    "src/assets/fonts/flags/flag-icon.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
  ],
  "assets": [
    "src/favicon.png",
    "src/assets",
  ],
```

I even tried adding the full path: `src/assets/fonts/flags/icons`, but it still builds them directly into the `dist` folder.

Comment: How did you "pulled all the files out of `node_modules`" ?

Comment: @Nicolas, I literally dragged the relevant files out of node_modules, then deleted the folder.  Everything is working properly, but the files are being saved in two places

Comment: Try to remove it using NPM `npm uninstall your-package` maybe there are some dependencies that loads the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All files added to `"styles": []` are always moved to the top level of the root '`/dist`' when builded. This is because they're global files.
More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options) under "styles".

You have multiple options to solve your problem:

Remove the "src/assets/fonts/flags/flag-icon.min.css" from the `"styles": [..]` array.

#### Option 1.

Import it into your `styles.scss` like:

```
@import('path/outside/assets/flag-icon.min.css')
```

Now they should be included in your `/dist/styles.css` after build. If you keep the icons inside the assets folder they will be imported to the `styles.css` and `/dist/assets/..` folder

#### Option 2

Import the icon set from your `index.html`

```
<link href="assets/fonts/flags/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you for these solutions! I am trying to consolidate my styles now and have run into a different error `ERROR in multi ./src/styles`, but I'll get that figured out separately.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Angular documentation is missing about this subject. It's documented [here](https://angular.io/cli/build) in ng build options, but it should also be documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#extra-build-and-test-options) (and it's not).

In angular.json, `projects.{projectName}.architect.build.options`, just add:

```json
"resourcesOutputPath": "{assets folder relative to ouput path}"
"outputPath": "{the generated app build (/dist is default}"
```

If you do not want to suffix resource file names with hashing code (you want icone-3cca4a8.svg instead of icone-3cca4a8.a00136cb93cdba1b0ea3.svg), add option:

```json
"outputHashing": "bundles", (instead of all)
```

So if your files are initially into **assets** and `resourcesOutputPath` points to **assets**, the files will be copied with the same directory and you will have one single copy of them.

Like all build options you can move them into a specific configuration (ie: `architect.build.configurations.production`)